# Save reference to private field (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, reference

I'm quite new to VB.NET programming and I have this situation:

I have one class Foo with some private fields (the number can be increased so I want to write some flexible code)  and its corresponding public readonly properties. For updating the values of the private fields, I have to read them in a OPC server. When I register to an OPCServer item, I get an integer, called ServerHandle, to identify it. Then, when I read the OPC server, I get several ServerHandles with its corresponding values, in the form of a dictionary (serverHandles as keys).

What I would like to create while creating my object, is a list of helper objects (I have called them Item) with only two public fields, ServerHandle and **a reference to a private field**, so I could do something like this when I get the dictionay of updates values:

```
Public Class Foo
    Private field1 As Double
    Private field2 As Double
    Private listOfitems As List(Of Item)

    Private Sub UpdateValues(dictionaryOfValues As Dictionary(Of Integer, Double))
        For Each item As Item In listOfitems
            item.Field = dictionaryOfValues(item.ServerHandle)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Item
    Public Field As Object
    Public ServerHandle As Integer
End Class
```

I know it is not possible to save a reference to a private field like this... but I would like to know if there is some way of doing something similar to what I'm trying.

If not... do you have any suggestions about how could I do this? (I have the feeling that I'm complicating my solution needlessly).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need some type of `public`ly exposed object on your `Foo` class, I suggest making a read-only public property for the `listOfItems`, like this:

```
Public Class Foo
    Private field1 As Double
    Private field2 As Double
    Private listOfitems As List(Of Item)

    Public Property ListOfItems() As List(Of Integer)
    Get
    Return listOfitems
    End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub UpdateValues(dictionaryOfValues As Dictionary(Of Integer, Double))
        For Each item As Item In listOfitems
            item.Field = dictionaryOfValues(item.ServerHandle)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```